# "Snapshot" of Historical Data for Analysis Purposes

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2019, data-warehouse, archive

I pull monthly aggregate data from a SQL database. I store the aggregated data in a separate table in the same database (so I can quickly grab numbers from six months ago, for instance).

My issue is that sometimes I am asked to pull details about the data from six months ago, but in our system the data is super dynamic and if I were to re-calculate my data from six months ago, I'd get different numbers than I did when I originally ran the data (because the underlying data has changed).

Contrived example: Number of users whose last name begins with "A". This data can change over time if a user changes their name.

I see a few high-level options:

1. Offload the details of the data each month into an excel spreadsheet, and save it in a file system (in the example above, we'd store a UserID and LastName) like *UserNames-2022-04-01.xlsx*
2. Make a timestamped copy of the critical data (Timestamp, UserID and LastName) in a separate database table, and use that for my aggregating and historical analysis
3. Similar to #2, but import the data into a data warehouse

I think the answer here is "Data Warehouse" but I want to be sure I am not missing a better/different approach.

Is there an approach that is considered best-practice in this scenario?

Comment: Primarily SQL Server 2019.

Comment: If the data does not change too often, then I would use triggers in the table such as the user table, to recalculate the aggregates.

Comment: Have you considered temporal tables and [`AS OF <date_time>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/querying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: @Martin Smith, that is not a feature I was very familiar with til yesterday, thank you- this is leading me in the right direction (this could be the answer!)